# How to deal with gspread quota exceded, error 429

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, error-handling, gspread

I'm trying to write stuff to a sheet, but I'm getting

`gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'Write requests per user per 100 seconds'....`

How Is It possible to edit my code so *It does not reachs the quota limit* OR *continue after some time that the quota has been reached*? Tried `time.sleep()` but It didn't work or I couldn't place that In the right place.

Here's my code for gspread

```
class CpfSearch(object):
    def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
        self.cpf_col = 1
        self.nome_col = 2
        self.age_col = 3
        self.beneficio_col = 4
        self.concessao_col = 5
        self.salario_col = 6
        self.bancos_col = 7
        self.bancocard_col = 8
        self.consig_col = 9
        self.card_col = 15

        scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)

        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1

    def process_cpf_list(self):

        # SKIP OVER COLUMN HEADING IN THE SPREADSHEET
        cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

        bot_url = BOT(cpfs)
        nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

        # UPDATE THE SHEET
        print("Atualizando...")

        for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])


cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase your time.sleep?  Right now it is right at the quota limit, so any slight differences might cause an error.  Try doubling the sleep and see if that works. Then back it off slowly to get it a bit faster.

Comment: Actually, it is way more than the quota limit. It looks like each time through the loop it is writing 9 times, making it 9 times the quota. So, increase time.sleep to 10 and see if that works.

Comment: You could also place a try/except block around each update_cell line with the except block having a 100 second sleep (to reset the quota), then redo that line and continue.

Comment: Could you please explain how to make that except in more detail? I'm very new programming, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I saw your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61198280/7108653 If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer, I would like to propose to create an array including the values and put the array to Spreadsheet using the method of `values_update`. The values can be put by one API call. By this, I thought that your issue might be resolved.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1
```

#### To:

```
self.spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name)
self.sheet = self.spreadsheet.sheet1
```

And

#### From:

```
for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
    time.sleep(1)
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])
```

#### To:

```
values = []
for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
    values.append([nomes[cpfs], idades[cpfs], beneficios[cpfs], concessoes[cpfs], salarios[cpfs], bancoss[cpfs], bancoscard[cpfs], consigs[cpfs], "", "", "", "", "", cards[cpfs]])
rng = "'" + self.sheet._properties['title'] + "'!B2"
self.spreadsheet.values_update(rng, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

### Reference:

- [values_update(range, params=None, body=None)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 9 API calls, by using update_cells rather than update_cell, you can reduce the number of API calls

I have tried to put a time.sleep(100) in an exception block, but that doesn't seem to work

```py
from gspread import Cell

        for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
            time. Sleep(1)
            c1 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
            c2 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
            c3 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
            c4 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
            c5 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salaries[cpfs])
            c6 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
            c7 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
            c8 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
            c9 = Cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cells([c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9])
```